# What makes a Champion a Viable Jungler?

Tags: league-of-legends

So, I main playing the bot lane, but I like to be capable in all positions. So what DOES make a jungle champion, a jungle champion? I know one key element is self-sustain, but at the same time, I know of several champions that are viable in the jungle, that have no real source of self-sustain. This includes a lot of the champions that are only "Glass Cannon" style junglers, such as Shaco, and a couple others, like Volibear. **I know Volibear's passive restores his health, but as it has 2 minute cool down, I don't consider it to be a sustain tool.** After looking at Shaco and some other glass cannons, I tried Talon in the jungle, and while it got the job done, it didn't feel like it was as strong as a jungler like Shaco, Kha'Zix or Master Yi. I want to know, is there some sort of common trait I can look for, to see who is the most viable in the jungle. Please keep in mind, that for me Viable doesn't necessarily mean that it works, it means it works well enough to be ***competitive* through *all* levels of play**. Please don't recommend things like jungle Leona or Jungle Sivir.

So in general, I guess I'm looking for how to determine if a champion can jungle well. How big a factor is sustain (Lifesteal/Spell Vamp/Mana Restore)? What kinds of damage output are needed? What about defenses? I'm looking for stats, not just general features.

Comment: @ColinD Opps. Didn't see that one. I read it over just now, and it comes close to answering my question, but not quite. Give me a minute or so to edit my question to be a bit more specific.

Comment: You may also find an answer [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/150110/decision-making-on-early-game-jungling/150114#150114) where I listed all the types of junglers and their main functions.

Answer (score 1):

Ordered in order of importance.

- Ability to GANK (stuns, snares, jumps and other engages).
- Ability to clear the jungle.
- Ability to duel the other jungler.
- Ability to move faster through the jungle.
- Ability to sustain itself in the jungle.
- Ability to secure buffs (all champions can take smite but Nunu and Cho'Gath have it easier).

What makes a champion a viable jungler is mostly it's ability to GANK.
This usually comes with gap closures, snares and/or stuns.
Also, farm, duelist, mobility and sustain are important.